# How to double click any where on web page?

Tags: selenium

```
Actions actions = new Actions(getDriver());

actions.moveByOffset(700,700);
actions.click().build().perform();


actions.moveByOffset(40,0);
actions.click().build().perform();

actions.moveByOffset(0,40);
actions.click().build().perform();


actions.moveByOffset(0,0);
actions.doubleClick().build().perform();
```

I can make it click but can't make it double click.

Do you have any idea ? How can i change this part of code .I need to double click any where on web page. Just a double click action .

```
actions.moveByOffset(0,0);
actions.doubleClick().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the **`Java Docs`** of current build of **`Selenium Java Client v3.8.1`** you cannot use **`public Actions doubleClick()`** as the documentation clearly mentions that [**`DoubleClickAction`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/package-summary.html) is **`Deprecated`**. Here is the snapshot :

[image: doubleClick]

Hence you may not be able to invoke **doubleClick()** from [**`Package org.openqa.selenium.interactions`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/package-summary.html)

### Solution :

If you need to execute **doubleClick()** two possible solutions are available as follows :

- Use [**`Actions.doubleClick(WebElement)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#doubleClick-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)
- Use **`JavascriptExecutor`** to inject a script defining **doubleClick()**.

Comment: How am going to invoke a JavaScript code from Java ?

Comment: It says right there in the docs what the alternative is... Use [Actions.doubleClick(WebElement)](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#doubleClick-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)

Comment: @JeffC The snapshot of `DoubleClickAction` which I have added in my `Answer` right from the beginning clearly mentions about the instruction to use **`Actions.doubleClick(WebElement)`** as an alternative. I have changed the verbatim of the Answer to make the even more clearer. Definitely **JavascriptExecutor** is a potential alternative. Let me know your thoughts about it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass element argument to doubleClick() menthod.

```
actions.doubleClick(anyClickableWebElement).build().perform();
```

Comment: But i am going to click on a google map so how am i going to pick an element .