# How can I double click on a ng-dblclick (webdriver) / not found selector

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, webdriver, double-click

I have a problem with an application that uses double click control, in the angular page I find an example of how it is implemented and I would like to double click on the example control but I can not get it

The example page is: [here](http://tutlane.com/example/angularjs/angularjs-double-click-ng-dblclick-example) together with output.

the button on the bottom has implemented the control with which I need to interact `ng-dblclick= getdetails()`

I tried to execute the js directly and use actions with xpath but it has not served

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("getdetails()");

new Actions(driver).DoubleClick(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/input"))).Perform();
```

What I can do?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/input"))).doubleClick().perform(); 
try this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make mouse double click in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981080/how-to-make-mouse-double-click-in-javascript)

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/input"}". It is strange because I wait for the control and the xpath statement copied it directly from the browser :(

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElemet(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/input")).DoubleClick().build.Perform();
```

or

```
WebElement element= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/input"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].dblclick();", element);
```

Comment: I have dealt with both forms but it always returns: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/input"}". It is strange because I wait for the control and the xpath statement copied it directly from the browser

Comment: please check with xpath