# How to double click this element using Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, double-click

I am working with the following element:

```
<p class="wrap button draggable" id="anonymous_element_1"><b class="icon" id="handler2"></b>Reports</p>
```

I have this code so far:

```
click_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="anonymous_element_1"]').click()
```

How can I double click on the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [**double_click**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47980355/7429447) on the element you can use [*`double_click()`*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.double_click) method from *ActionChains* implementation inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) as follows:

```
ActionChains(driver).double_click(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[@class='wrap button draggable' and @id='anonymous_element_1'][contains(., 'Reports')]")))).perform()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: When I run the above code I receive the following error:
NameError: name 'ActionChains' is not defined
I have the following imports in my code so far:

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

Comment: @HamidBee Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

Xyz.click(); Thread.sleep(10); Xyz.click();

?